# b'data.csv' does not exist

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have been given a csv file which I am trying to read as a pandas dataframe using pd.read_csv. I get an error - "data.csv" does not exist. The python script and the the datafile exist in the same folder.  A jupyter notebook has no problem reading the file as a pandas dataframe.

> PathName=1.filename 2.absolute path to the file 3. place file in a
>   different folder and insert relative path name , encoding='UTF-8'

```
inputdata = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep='\t',encoding='UTF-8')
```

inputdata should be able to read the contents of the file as a pandas dataframe

Comment: Try
`import os
filename = os.path.join((os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'data.csv')
inputdata = pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\t',encoding='UTF-8')`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're executing your script by `python path/to/my/script.py`. It tries to find `data.csv` in the current working directory that is different from the directory where your script and the data file reside.
Try

```
import os
filename = os.path.join((os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'data.csv')
inputdata = pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\t',encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23487217)

Comment: Where do you know from that this does not solve the problem? I guess he's calling the script from another directory, so data.csv is not in the current working directory. Hence my answer.

Comment: Thanks Stef, this was very helpful

Comment: You're welcome! If it solved your problem, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).